# C++ - typedef/using for function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I've got a following function template:

```
template<class A, class C, class B>
A doFoo(const B &val)
{
  //do something with C
}
```

Within my cpp file, all *doFoo* function will be used with one type for `C`. Is it possible to do such kind of typedef:

```
typedef myDoFoo<A, B> doFoo<A, ParticularC, B>
```

If it is - what is a correct syntax to do this?

Comment: What is `E`? What is "will be used with"? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Except you may not (as the article states).

Answer (score 7):

Just define another template function:

```
template<class A, class B>
A myDoFoo(const B &val)
{
  return doFoo<A,ParticularC,B>( val );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You may write a function:

```
template<class A, class B>
A myDoFoo(const B &val)
{
    return doFoo<A, ParticularC, B>(val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using variable templates (available in GCC since version 5), you can define a reference to your function:

```
template<class A, class B> auto &myDoFoo = doFoo<A, ParticularC, B>;
```

or more explicitly

```
template<class A, class B> A (&myDoFoo)(const B &) = doFoo<A, ParticularC, B>;
```

Comment: However, this way, no template arguments are deduced. You must always call it as `myDoFoo<int, char>(x)`, even if `x` is already known to be `char`. This may or may not be acceptable.